# Detect full human head in a photo

Tags: face-detection

I have a passport-sized photo with truncated head, I would like to build an application to detect if the photo has full head or not. I have checked face alignment , Mtcnn and others, but all of these libraries focus on facial features rather than the entire head shape.

Theoretically, this can be accomplished by detecting head curvature in the upper portion of the image. If there are none, then the photo is truncated or a full human head is not present.

Appreciate your help on how to implement this or advise on better solution. I’ve seen some solution using haar cascade classification. I am looking here more of simple shape detection using cv2.

Comment: Which kind of photo backgrounds do you have?